# How to include a module which name is stored in a variable?

Tags: ruby

Trying to dynamically include a module :

```
module_name = "Foo"
extend {#module_name} # Wanting to do `extend Foo` dynamically
```

It wont pass as a parameter

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+)
```

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pure ruby, you can do

```
extend Object.const_get(module_name)
```

or a less beautiful approach, like

```
eval "extend #{module_name}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [activesupport](http://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport) gem and [String#constantize](http://apidock.com/rails/String/constantize) method for that:

```
require 'active_support/inflector'

module_name = 'Foo'
extend module_name.constantize
```

Comment: No need to bring activesupport. Simple `const_get` should suffice

Comment: true, it seems overkill to include a gem for just this purpose

Comment: This solution is appropriate for ruby < 2.0, as `Module.const_get` wasn't able to resolve namespaced constants up to ruby 1.9.3. As of ruby 2.0, `Module.const_get` (or `Object.const_get`) resolves namespaced classes, so active_support's `#constantize` is not necessary anymore.

Answer (score 1):

```
module_name = "Foo"
eval "extend #{module_name}"
```

or

```
require 'active_support/inflector'

module_name = "Foo"
extend module_name.constantize
```

or

```
module_name = "Foo"
extend Object.const_get(module_name)
```